# How does nom have a macro invocation in a macro designator position?

Tags: macros, rust

In the following example, taken from `nom`, the argument `$submac` has `ident!( $($args:tt)* )` in designator-position. I'm under the impression that `ident!(...)` is a macro invocation, yet as far as I can see `nom` does not define a macro named `ident`. Rust's documentation on macros does not specify that macro-invocations can even appear in designator-position.

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! exact (
  ($i:expr, $submac:ident!( $($args:tt)* )) => ({
      terminated!($i, $submac!( $($args)*), eof!())
  });
  ($i:expr, $f:expr) => (
    exact!($i, call!($f));
  );
);
```

What is `ident!(...)` in formal syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm under the impression that `ident!(...)` is a macro invocation

It is not. It's something that deliberately *looks like* a macro invocation though. Adding a space would probably make it more obvious:

```
macro_rules! example {
    ($foo:ident !) => (1);
}

fn main() {
    example!(hello!);
}
```